# LinkedIn Javascript API authorization in IE9 failed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I've noticed that LinkedIn Javascript API authorization is not working in IE9. Code snippet is the following

```
if (!IN.User.isAuthorized()) {
    IN.User.authorize(getProfile);
} else {
    getProfile();
}
```

`getProfile()` callback method never called. After `IN.User.authorize()` call browser opens a popup window, tries to load some LinkedIn resource (my case  https://platform.linkedin.com/js/xdrpc.html?v=0.0.2000-RC8.50730-1428#), and once loading is finished window remains blank with "Processing" text in the title.

In Chrome and Firefox all works ok. And If I correctly remember, this worked earlier (a couple months ago).

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Turning Off the Protected mode setting in internet explorer.
For disabling protected mode in internet explorer go to Internet Options -> Security -> Internet.There you will find "Enable protected Mode".Just disable it.